# Automating installer testing

Tags: windows, automation, windows-installer

Are there any good frameworks for automating windows installer testing? Am looking at black box testing. Trivial test cases would include verifying if installer places files under respective locations and so on.

I can develop a simple tool to do that but wanted to know if there's any framework that could help me here.

Comment: Nothing that I know of. I've had developers ask me for this over the years but I never understood why.  Windows Installer is a declarative language.  When you say install file X o dir Y it will do it.  Now you have to maintain two sets of meta for very little value add.

Comment: I agree with Chris - it's like saying you're using Explorer to copy files around and you want to make it copies the files. You're basically testing that Microsoft's code is working, why? The real problem is likely to be your custom action code not working correctly, that's what needs inspecting and testing for correct operation, not that files are installed.

Answer (score 0):

There is [pywinauto](http://pywinauto.github.io/) UI automation framework written as Python package. Embedded Python module `os.path` contains all necessary functions for file placement checks.


AutoIT is also widely known automation tool but it has own strange scripting language.